# Not able to display details of RowRepeater selected first row in detail page

Tags: data-binding, sapui5, binding-context

I have one sapui5 application and we have upgraded the application sapui5 version from 1.44 to 1.56.

In this application we are using RowRepeater control. We have two views one is Master and other is detail view.

Whenever I select a row in Master view the corresponding details of the selected row should be displayed in detail view.

In detail view we are using two Comboboxes for drop downs and some Text controls as well.

Problem:

The functionlaity was working fine in 1.44 version but after upgrade the functionlaity is working except for first row.
Whenever I select first row the row details are displaying correctly but the Comboboxes are not displaying the selected values. I guess they are resetting to default values.

Please find teh code below:

Master.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.test.components.notes.controller.Master" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:commons="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<ScrollContainer height="30rem" width="100%" horizontal="false" vertical="true" focusable="false">
    <commons:RowRepeater id="notes" design="Transparent" numberOfRows="50" sort=".rowRepeatSort">
        <commons:rows>
            <layout:HorizontalLayout id="RowTemp" class="npcRowRepeat">
                <commons:Image class="npcStatusBar"></commons:Image>
                <layout:VerticalLayout>
                    <commons:TextView text="{Subject}" width="18rem" wrapping="false" class="formLabel" design="Bold"/>
                    <commons:TextView text="{path : 'Text', formatter: '.formatString'}" width="12rem" wrapping="false" class=" formLabel"/>
                </layout:VerticalLayout>
                <layout:VerticalLayout id="TextTypeRow">
                    <commons:TextView text="{ImpactDesc}" width="12rem" wrapping="false" class="formLabel" design="Bold"/>
                    <commons:TextView text="{TextType}" width="12rem" wrapping="false" class="formLabel"/>
                </layout:VerticalLayout>
                <layout:VerticalLayout>
                    <commons:TextView text="{ path : 'DateSystem', formatter: '.formatDate' }" width="5rem" wrapping="true" class="formLabel"/>
                </layout:VerticalLayout>
            </layout:HorizontalLayout>
        </commons:rows>
    </commons:RowRepeater>
</ScrollContainer>
```

Detail.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.test.components.notes.controller.Detail" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:commons="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:rich="sap.ui.richtexteditor" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
<form:Form class="editableForm" id="NOTES_FORM">
    <form:title>
    </form:title>
    <form:layout>
        <form:ResponsiveGridLayout columnsM="1" columnsL="1" labelSpanL="6" labelSpanS="4" labelSpanM="6" emptySpanL="2" emptySpanM="2" emptySpanS="2" />
    </form:layout>
    <form:formContainers>
        <form:FormContainer>
            <form:formElements>
                <form:FormElement>
                    <form:fields>
                        <commons:Label id="typeLabel" text="{i18n>Type_Form}" class="formLabel" required="true"  />
                        <ComboBox id="type" class="formLabel" placeholder="{i18n>SELECT_NOTE_TYPE}"  selectedKey="{TextId}"  selectionChange=".onValidateForm" editable="true" width="14.5rem">
                            <core:Item id="typeItem" key="{TextId}" text="{TextType}" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </form:fields>
                </form:FormElement>
            </form:formElements>
        </form:FormContainer>
        <form:FormContainer>
            <form:formElements>
                <form:FormElement>
                    <form:fields>
                        <commons:Label id="priorityLabel" text="{i18n>Priority_Form}" class="formLabel" required="true" />
                        <ComboBox id="priority"  placeholder="{i18n>SELECT_NOTE_PRIORITY}" selectedKey="{Impact}" selectionChange=".onValidateForm" class="formLabel" width="14.5rem">
                            <core:Item id="impactItem" key="{Impact}" text="{Description}" tooltip="{Description}" />
                        </ComboBox>
                    </form:fields>
                </form:FormElement>
            </form:formElements>
        </form:FormContainer>
        <form:FormContainer>
            <form:formElements>
                <form:FormElement>
                    <form:fields>
                        <commons:Label id="subjectLabel" text="{/#Notes/Subject/@sap:label}" class="formLabel" required="true" />
                        <Input id="subject" value="{Subject}" placeholder="{i18n>ENTER_NOTE_SUBJECT}"   editable="true" class="formLabel" width="14.5rem" maxLength="40" liveChange="onSubjectLC" valueStateText="Maximum 40 Characters Allowed" />

                    </form:fields>
                </form:FormElement>
            </form:formElements>
        </form:FormContainer>

    </form:formContainers>
</form:Form>
```

Master.controller.js:

```
sap.ui.define(["com/test/library/common/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/commons/TextView",
    "sap/ui/commons/RowRepeaterFilter",
    "sap/ui/commons/RowRepeaterSorter"
],
function(BaseController, Dialog, TextView, RowRepeaterFilter, RowRepeaterSorter, Sorter, Filter, FilterOperator) {
    "use strict";
    return BaseController.extend("com.test.components.notes.controller.Master", {
        _sChannelId: "notes",
        _oMainController: "",

        onInit: function(oEvent) {
            BaseController.prototype.onInit.apply(this);
            this.oNotes = this.oView.byId("notes");
            this.oBundle = this.getComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
            this.oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
            this.oComponent.oNotesMainController = this;
            this.oComponent.oNotesRepeater = this.oNotes;

            var that = this;

            if (!this.oTemplate) {
                this.oTemplate = this.byId("RowTemp").clone();

                var fnOnClick = function(oEvent) { 
                    var oCreateMode = this.oComponent._oViewModel.getProperty("/CreateMode");
                    if (oCreateMode === false) {
                        that._oModel.deleteCreatedEntry(that._oContext);
                    }

                    //Higlight selected row 
                    var sSelectedRowId = jQuery(oEvent.target).closest(".npcRowRepeat").attr("id");
                    var oSelectedRow;

                    this.oNotes.getRows().forEach(function(oRow, index) {
                        var bSelected = sSelectedRowId === oRow.getId();
                        oRow.toggleStyleClass("npcSelectedRow", bSelected); 

                        if (bSelected) {
                            oSelectedRow = oRow;
                        }
                    });

                    this.onRowSelect(oSelectedRow.getBindingContext());

                }.bind(this);

                this.oTemplate.addEventDelegate({
                    onclick: fnOnClick
                });

                this.oTemplate.addEventDelegate({
                    onAfterRendering: function() {
                        var oFirstRow = that.oNotes.getRows()[0].getId();
                        var oStyle = that.oNotes.getRows()[0].aCustomStyleClasses.indexOf("npcSelectedRow");
                        if (oFirstRow && oStyle === -1 && oUpdate == false) {
                            $("#" + oFirstRow).trigger("click");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        },
        onRowSelect: function(oContext) {
            this.getEventBus().publish(this._sChannelId, "refreshNotesForm", {
                context: oContext,
            });
        }

     });
});
```

Detail.controller.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "com/test/library/common/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/m/MessageToast"
], function(BaseController, MessageToast) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("com.test.components.notes.controller.Detail", {
        _sNotesCollection: "Notes",

        _sChannelId: "notes",
        _oMainController: "",

        /**
         * on init
         *
         */
        onInit: function() {
            BaseController.prototype.onInit.apply(this);
            this._oForm = this._oView.byId("NOTES_FORM");
            this.oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();

            this._oBundle = this.getComponent().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();

            var that = this;



            if (!this.oTemplate) {
                this.oTypeTemplate = this.byId("typeItem").clone();
                this.oImpactTemplate = this.byId("impactItem").clone();
            }

            this.getEventBus().subscribe("notes", "refreshNotesForm",
                function(sChannelId, sEventId, oData) {

                    that._oContext = oData.context;
                    that._oForm.setBindingContext(oData.context);
                    that.currentValueNotes = that.getView().byId("notes").getValue();


                });
        }

    });
});
```

Output image for first selected row of RowRepeater in details page:

[image]

Output image for second selected row of RowRepeater in details page(which is working fine):

[image]

Please guide me in this.